# Is there a way to add/delete editors' access to protected cells dynamically by checkbox values on a Google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, access-rights

I am new to Google Apps Scripts and am puzzled with the problem of manipulating access of different editors. I have over 10 sheets and 20 editors, and I need to allocate their access rights according to their roles. I am thinking of using checkboxes for adding and deleting their access rights. So far these two are the codes I have picked up from the others. One for showing and hiding the timestamps by checking/unchecking the boxes, whilst another for adding and deleting the editors.

***For Timestamps***

```
function runEmailAccess(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sEditors = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet Name');
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Sheet ID");

var nAddEditor = sEditors.getRange('A2').getValue();
if (nAddEditor != 0){
var vAddEditor = sEditors.getRange('A3:A'+nAddEditor).getValues();
sheet.addEditors(vAddEditor);
 }

var nRemoveEditor = sEditors.getRange('B2').getValue();
if (nRemoveEditor != 0){
var vRemoveEditor = sEditors.getRange('B3:B'+nRemoveEditor).getValues();

for (j=0;j<vRemoveEditor.length;j++) {
  sheet.removeEditor(vRemoveEditor[j][0])
}
}

}
```

***For checkboxes***

```
function onEdit(e){
  if (e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.columnEnd == 6 && e.range.rowStart <= 20) {
    var ckeckboxRange = "F1:F20";
    var date = new Date();
    var range = e.source.getRange(ckeckboxRange);
    var values = range.getValues().map(function(e) {return e[0] === true ? [date] : [""]});
    range.offset(0, 1).setValues(values);
  }
}

var SpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var editors = SpreadSheet.getEditors();
for (var i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
     SpreadSheet.removeEditor(editors[i]);
    };
```

And finally we have the expected outcome as it would be a clearer picture of what I have described. It is like a command portal to control different access rights on a holistic level.

[Expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwKB6.png)

Many thanks to all useful comments.

Comment: What are `Sheet1`, `Sheet2` etc.? Are they separate spreadsheets or sheets within the active spreadsheet?

Comment: @ziganotschka They are both, like `tab 1` and `tab 2`  from spreadsheet 1, and `tab A` and `tab B` from spreadsheet 2. Thanks for asking so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You need the the following components:

- onEdit trigger
- Checking which checkbox has been edited and making the connection to the respective sheet
- Retrieve the editor from the line wiht the checkbox
- Verify either the box has been checked or unechecked

Below is a sample providing this funcitonality:

```js
function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //change name of the sheet if necessary!
  var sheetWithCheckBoxes = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var column =  e.range.getColumn();
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() == sheetWithCheckBoxes.getName() && (column == 3 || column == 4 || column == 5)) {
    Logger.log("if");
    var spreadsheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXX");
    var sheet;
    switch (column){
      case 3:
        sheet = ss.getSheetByName("name");
        break;
      case 4:
        sheet = ss.getSheetByName("name2");
        break;
      case 5:
        sheet = spreadsheet2.getSheetByName("name3");
        break;
    }       
   
    var protection = sheet.protect();
    if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
      protection.setDomainEdit(false);
    }
    var editor = sheetWithCheckBoxes.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 2).getValue();
     Logger.log(e.value);
    if(e.value == "TRUE"){
       Logger.log("true");
      protection.addEditor(editor);
    }
    if(e.value == "FALSE"){
            Logger.log("false");
      protection.removeEditor(editor);
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:**
In this sample the first two sheets are in the same spreadsheet like the sheet with the checkboxes and the wthird dsheet is in a different spreadsheet.

Please adapt the sheets and spreadsheets accoring to you needs.

### UPDATE

For setting not only the sheet protection, but also share the spreadsheet with new users, you need to use the method [DriveApp.getFileById(id).addEditor(editor)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#addeditoremailaddress).

However, `DriveApp.getFileById(id)` is a call that cannot be triggered with a simple onEdit trigger due to [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions).

**Solution:**

[Bind](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) an [installable onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) to your function instead of the simple one. Make sure to rename the function beforehand to avoid conflicts because of the simple and installable trigger being fired simultaneously.

Sample setting up both the spreadsheet and sheet permissions:

```js
function Edit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //change name of the sheet if necessary!
  var sheetWithCheckBoxes = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var column =  e.range.getColumn();
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() == sheetWithCheckBoxes.getName() && (column == 3 || column == 4 || column == 5)) {
    var spreadsheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXX");
    var sheet;
    var id;
    switch (column){
      case 3:
        sheet = ss.getSheetByName("name");
        id = ss.getId();
        break;
      case 4:
        sheet = ss.getSheetByName("name2");
        id = ss.getId();
        break;
      case 5:
        id = spreadsheet2.getId();
        sheet = spreadsheet2.getSheetByName("name3");
        break;
    }       
    var protection = sheet.protect();
    if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
      protection.setDomainEdit(false);
    }
    var editor = sheetWithCheckBoxes.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 2).getValue();
    Logger.log(e.value);
    if(e.value == "TRUE"){
      DriveApp.getFileById(id).addEditor(editor);
      protection.addEditor(editor);
    }
    if(e.value == "FALSE"){
      protection.removeEditor(editor);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That is really helpful! But I do not see any changes so far in the access rights after I check/uncheck the boxes. I guess something is wrong with other scripts that may disrupt the checkboxes' functions, or the no. of sheets has affected the codes, or that is something else?

Comment: The script changes the permissions for individual sheets of spreadsheets that have already been shared. Is it what you wanted or do the spreadsheets also need to be shared by script in the first place? Make sure you do not have more than one onEdit function per project.

Comment: Sorry if I did not explain clearly at the very beginning. I would like to restrict/provide access to people who I have never shared the whole spreadsheet with. Like if I solely check the box and let them access tab1 of spreadsheet1, they wont be able to access to tab2 of spreadsheet1. So yes I want the spreadsheets to be shared at the first place as well. On the other hand, will onOpen affect the onEdit as well? I have already deleted all other onEdit functions before this but still in vain. Thank you very much.

Comment: No, onOpen should not cause problems. I updated my solution with a code that shares the spreadsheet with the ticked users before giving them access to the ticked sheets. Make sure to bind the function to an INSTALLABLE onEdit trigger.

Comment: Thanks for more info.! I have added the INSTALLABLE Trigger in 'Add Triggers' and it runs the function as the sheet is edited. I think I am almost there as I find one small error. It shows `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined "` , referring to `var column =  e.range.getColumn();` , as I run the function manually through macros. Any thought for this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: functions running on trigger and containin [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) like e.g. `e.range` cannot be run manually - only automatically when the trigger fires.

Comment: I see thanks a lot! Is it normal to have latency in this issue? I successfully shared sheets with the others but in vain after I changed from sharing active sheets (with checkboxes) from Master spreadsheet to other spreadsheets. And basically sharing one sheet will also lead to the sharing of other sheets in the same spreadsheet, that it is better for me to control access of other sheets at the same time, am I correct? Thanks!

Comment: When you share a spreadsheet, by default you share all sheets it contains. As the script is now, it sets a protection on the sheets where the checkbox is being edited. You can implement a different functionality where you protect all sheets you don't want to share. Especially you might be interested in protecting the master sheet with the checkboxes so nobody can edit them apart from you.